# Method for Hibernate Select

Tags: java, hibernate

I got this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("
    from Osoba 
        WHERE (zainteresowania LIKE '%iOS%') 
        and (zainteresowania LIKE '%Java%') 
        and (zainteresowania LIKE '%Android%')"
    );
```

That works fine, but I need a method that will ask me: What do you want to search? And I can tell it something like: Android  and  Ubuntu
that means it has to search for those 2 phraes in database in col zainteresowania and if somebody has it, then I print it.

As I said this is the example how it is stored in that col:

1. Java
2. Platforma .NET (C#)
3. Android
4. iOS
5. Windows Phone
6. Testowanie aplikacji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either positioned parameters or numbered parameters as explained below to pass parameters dynamically to your SQL queries:

**Positioned Parameters**

```
 String input1=// got from user
    String input2=// got from user
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Osoba WHERE (zainteresowania LIKE ?) and (zainteresowania LIKE ?)")
.setString(0,"%"+input1+"%")
.setString(1,"%"+input2+"%")
.list();
```

**Named Parameters:**

```
String hql = "from Osoba WHERE (zainteresowania LIKE :user_input1) and (zainteresowania LIKE :user_input2)";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter("user_input1", "%Java%")
.setParameter("user_input2","%Android%");
.list();
```

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/) for more information.

Comment: In positioned parameters, you mean `.setString(1,"%"+input2+"%")` and I think the second method would be _Named Parameters_, instead of _Numbered Parameters_.

Comment: ok, but is there a way to dynamiclly decide how many parametrs user pass?

Answer (score 0):

Your way helped me much. I also was able to "dynamicly" do it.

Here's my code:

```
 String input3 = ("");
       String input4 = ("");
       String input5 = ("");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("First");
          String input1 = in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Second(empty field to break)");
          String input2 = in.nextLine();
          if (!input2.isEmpty())
                  {
          System.out.println("Third(empty field to break)");
          input3 = in.nextLine();          
          if (!input3.isEmpty())
                 {
          System.out.println("Fourth(empty field to break)");
          input4 = in.nextLine();   
          if (!input4.isEmpty())
                 {
          System.out.println("Fifth(empty field to break)");
          input5 = in.nextLine();
                 }       
                 }
                 }



          Query query = session.createQuery("from Osoba WHERE (zainteresowania LIKE ?) and (zainteresowania LIKE ?) and (zainteresowania LIKE ?) and (zainteresowania LIKE ?) and (zainteresowania LIKE ?)");
          query.setString(0,"%"+input1+"%");
          query.setString(1,"%"+input2+"%");
          query.setString(2,"%"+input3+"%");
          query.setString(3,"%"+input4+"%");
          query.setString(4,"%"+input5+"%");
```